# How to get response text from ajax callback in a variable using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I wonder if I can get the `responseText` from an `Ext.Ajax.Request` call in a variable. I've tried many ways and *"hacks"* without success.

### Example:

In this case, I am trying to assign the `responseText` to the `accStatus` variable and I am always getting `undefined` (I know this is ***NOT*** the right way) but I want to know exactly **how to handle this** (the correct way) and `return` it in my `function` without problems and in a *"simple"* way (if possible) like the below code.

*By the way, I am using **Ext 4.2.0**.*

---

### Is there a way to do something like this?

```
Ext.define('Util.AccountManager', { 

    singleton: true,

    getAccountStatus: function(id) {
        var accStatus;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'rest/accounts',
            method : 'POST',
            params : {id: id},
            callback: function(o, s, r) {
                accStatus = r.responseText;
            }
        });

        return accStatus;
    }

});

Ext.onReady(function () {

    var id = '1234';
    var accStatus = Util.AccountManager.getAccountStatus(id);

    if(accStatus) {
        console.log(accStatus);
    }

});
```

---

*If someone wants to help on this, you can use the following `URLs` for importing `ExtJS`:*

- http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js
- http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css

*I also made this `jsfiddle` just for "testing" (or at least trying because it is not possible to make `ajax` requests through this site).*

- http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/aE6fz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getAccountStatus` needs a callback so you can respond after the XHR finishes. AJAX is asynchronous so you cannot expect your success callback to be called before your call to `getAccountStatus` returns;

```
// Will never work unless you use synchronous AJAX (which you shouldn't
// because it would block the UI while the request is pending)
var accStatus = Util.AccountManager.getAccountStatus(id);
```

Do the following instead

```
Ext.define('Util.AccountManager', { 

    singleton: true,

    getAccountStatus: function(id, cb) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'rest/accounts',
            method : 'POST',
            // async: true, // This would make your return work, but don't do it
            params : {id: id},
            callback: function(o, s, r) {
                cb(r.responseText);
            }
        });

        // Code here runs before the callback above
    }    
});

Ext.onReady(function () {    
    var id = '1234';
    var accStatus = Util.AccountManager.getAccountStatus(id, function(status){
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I assign it to `accStatus` variable when doing the `callback`? Do I need to just do `return status;` instead of `console.log(accStatus);` in order to get it? By the way, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @OscarJara  by the time your callback is called, `getAccountStatus` has already returned (because it's asynchronous), that's why you're getting `undefined`. When the callback is called, you are setting that variable but it's never being used. You need to read up on asynchronous code to grasp the concept. You cannot turn an asynchronous operations (where you get the result from the callback) into a synchronous operation (where you get the result from the return value). Your code will work if you pass `async: false` to Ext.Ajax.request... but you shouldn't because it'll block the UI

Comment: Oh, I got the idea (is just a matter of analyzing it). I think it's ok that I can handle `accStatus` in the `callback`. Maybe I can isolate it in another `function`, thanks for your time Juan and for sharing the *"right way"*. I am more familiar with `jQuery` and there are some tricks which I can't do in `ExtJS` (that's why I asked this question).

Comment: @OscarJara This is not ExtJS specific. Remember that `jQuery` is also asynchronous where it uses XHR. You can't do `function getSomething(){return $.ajax()}`, you have to use callbacks. Again, you cannot *wrap* async code and try to make it look synchronous

Comment: Yes, I know that, one thing is *"how ajax calls work"* and other the `Ext.Ajax.Request` from `ExtJS`. I was trying to let your know that in `jQuery` there are more *"hacks"* and also some functions like `.get()` that allows you to get the `response` (different from `ExtJS` but a really good framework) thanks for your help.

Comment: I see, the hack in ExtJs is `async: false`